# Asymptotic upper bound $T(n)=(T(n−1))^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> The question is to find asymptotic upper bound for recurrence:
>
> $T(n)=(T(n−1))^2$
>
> $T(n) = \text{n for  n} \leq 2$

---

My attempt:

I've tried to use substitution method and getting:

$T(n) = (T(n-1))^2 = ((T(n-2))^2)^2 = (((T(n-3))^2)^2)^2$ etc.

I couldn't find a way to express n number of powers of 2's.

> Can you explain in formal way? Please.

Comment: tbh, i don't really understand my attempt, but if anyone knows how to find the asymptotic upper bound for this recurrence, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(n) = T(n-k)^{2^k}$ (for $k < n-2$)

you can prove this by induction:

for k=1:
$$T(n) = T(n-1)^2$$

and the induction step:

$$T(n) = T(n-k)^{2^k} = (T(n-k-1)^2)^{2^k}=T(n-(k+1))^{2^{k+1}}$$

now take $k=n-3$:
$$T(n) = T(n-(n-3))^{2^{n-3}} = T(3)^{2^{n-3}} = 2^{2^{n-2}}$$

Comment: what is the asymptotic upper bound in this case? My understanding on asymptotic upper bound is quite poor.

Comment: $T(n) = O(2^{2^{n-2}})$

Comment: Thank you very much! btw is it better to write it as O(2^2^n) instead